# various Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorems $ \sum \frac{a_n nx^n}{1-x^n} \to \frac{A}{1-x} $ implies $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = A$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory

I am seeing the Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian Theorem phrased in several different ways.  Are they all equivalent?

**A** If $\sum  a_n x^n \sim \frac{1}{1-x}$ then $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k = n$

**B** If $\sum a_n e^{-ny} = \frac{1}{y}$ then $ \sum_{k=0}^n a_k = n$

Thse are obviously related by a change of variables.  How about this one?

**C** If $ \sum \frac{a_n nx^n}{1-x^n} \to \frac{A}{1-x} $ and $ n a_n > -1$ then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k = A$

---

Karamata shows **A** and **B** using a lemma:

$$ \lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)\sum a_n x^n g(x) = \int_0^1 g(t) \, dt$$

using a certain choice of $g(x)$ he proves **A** and **B**.   Is it also possible to prove **C** this way?

I don't know if that is also considered the [Hardy-Littlewood Tauberian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem).  Wikipedia says yes, other sources indicate [no](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968102?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).  Hardy and Littlewood wrote many Tauberian Theorems.   Other places I have looked:

- Widder [The Laplace Transform](https://archive.org/details/laplacetransform031816mbp)
- Titchmarsh [Theory of Functions](https://archive.org/details/TheTheoryOfFunctions)

I thought for a while **C** was the the same as **A** and **B** then I realized it wasn't.  Still not entirely sure either way.

---

*A* and **B** amount to the [Weierstrass approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem).  What kind of approximations is one making in **C**? If $x \approx 1$:

$$ \sum a_n \approx
\sum  a_n  x^n
 \approx  (1-x)\sum \frac{a_n n x^n}{1-x^n}
\approx A  \tag{$\ast$} $$

This shows that **C** in a way is kind of obvious if only this line of reasoning were precise.

Comment: Have you looked at J. Korevaar's  2004  massive Springer  monograph *TauberianTheory. A Century of Developments*?

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu I can't neatly improve **A** $\to **B** or  **B** $\to **A** prove both of them from Karmata's lemma... just I don't really trust myself.  The power series and the [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) are both instances of Stieltjes integrals..  This book is HUGE.

Comment: I honestly cannot help you with this since I have not thought about these issues in a very long time.  However that book is the most likely place to contain useful  ideas.